# Oracle PDO OCI charset failing

Tags: oracle, nginx, pdo, php

I am using the instant oracle client 11.2, php 5.5.16 compiled from sources with the following configure arguments:

`'./configure' '--enable-fpm' '--enable-bcmath' '--with-bz2' '--enable-calendar' '--with-curl' '--enable-dba' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--with-gd' '--with-gettext' '--with-kerberos' '--enable-mbstring' '--with-mcrypt' '--with-openssl' '--enable-shmop' '--enable-soap' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-sysvmsg' '--enable-wddx' '--enable-zip' '--with-zlib' '--with-xsl' '--with-mysql' '--with-mysqli' '--with-pgsql' '--with-pdo-mysql' '--with-pdo-pgsql' '--with-oci8' '--with-pdo-oci'`

On my previous configuration I was using apache2 (`--with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs2` instead of `--enable-fpm`) with oracle and oci8. My *Data Source Name* is: `"oci:dbname=//IP:1521/SID;charset=UTF8"`.
It was working just fine.

Today I wanted to move this server configuration from apache to nginx and fpm. Everything is working fine except that, on connection, PDO throws :

`OCIEnvNlsCreate: Check the character set is valid and that PHP has access to Oracle libraries and NLS data`

I've got the exact same configuration except for php-fpm handling php instead of apxs.

If I remove the `charset=UTF8` part it works but obviously I got charset errors. I've added to my `php_fpm.conf` the `env[NLS_LANG]=FRENCH_FRANCE.UTF8` environment variable with no success.

What can I do to make the nginx/php-fpm configuration to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading again the comment on the [oci8 installation php page](http://php.net/manual/it/oci8.installation.php#110226) I've fixed the issue.

The fact is that, even if that's mentioned in the [oracle php docs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/php/201212-ug-php-oracle-1884760.pdf), setting environnement variables in the `php_fpm.conf` does not work!

You have to:

1. Write an oracle specific profile to `vim /etc/profile.d/oracle.sh`

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64
   C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/oracle/11.2/client64
   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib
   #remember this is the client NLS_LANG not the server one
   NLS_LANG=FRENCH_FRANCE.UTF8 
   export ORACLE_HOME LD_LIBRARY_PATH NLS_LANG
   ```
2. Add this to the `/etc/init.d/php-fpm`

   `. /etc/profile.d/oracle.sh`

Answer (score 1):

Solved this problem today. In my case the problem was only in 1 environment variable: `ORACLE_HOME`.

If i run the script with php-cli, then ORACLE_HOME is set to /usr/lib and everything works fine, so charset=UTF8 in dsn is ok.

But if i run the same script with php-fpm, then ORACLE_HOME is not set, and only this is the reason for charset=UTF8 in dsn to break the runtime.

So my solution was add this:

```
putenv('ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib');
```

to my php script.
Don't need to set no other variables.
So setting `NLS_LANG`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or `C_INCLUDE_PATH` is **redundant**.

Answer (score 0):

Solved adding the environment vars to **php-fpm.conf** like this:

```
; ORACLE
env[ORACLE_HOME] = /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64
env[C_INCLUDE_PATH] = /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64
env[LD_LIBRARY_PATH] = /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib
env[NLS_LANG] = AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8
```